# Python - Save images from a list of urls in a text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to download multiple images from a text file that I created. I tried so many things but couldn't figured it out.

Textfile looks something like this:

```
website.com/00.jpg
website.com/01.jpg
website.com/02.jpg
.
.
.
website.com/45.jpg
```

Comment: Show your best try.

Comment: Because of frustration I deleted it. Shouldn't have done that...

Answer (score 0):

Show your python code so I know what you're trying to do so far

Comment: Because of frustration I deleted it. Shouldn't have done that...

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a start. This is how you can save a file

```
import requests

def save_file(file_url, file_path):
    r = requests.get(file_url)
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(r.content)


save_file('https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200316132641-03-supreme-court-0316-large-tease.jpg', 'test.jpg')
```

For the easy part, reading lines from a text file, there are lots of examples to find. If you can't figure it out, post your code and ask a solution.